# newcommand with parameter blank or zero

Tags: macros

i read code in other topic: definited newcommand selectTask.

IF TaskOne/TaskTwo = blank is ok.

Now i want to edit IF TaskOne/TaskTwo = blank or zero (0).

Please help update this code:

```
\newcommand{\selectTask}[2]{%
  \if\relax#1\relax
    \if\relax#2\relax
      \selectTaskA % 00 TaskOne = TaskTwo=blank => How if blank or zero?
    \else
      \selectTaskB % 01 TaskOne =blank,TaskTwo=!=blank
    \fi
  \else
    \if\relax#2\relax
      \selectTaskC % 10  TaskOne !=blank, TaskTwo=blank
    \else
      \selectTaskD % 11 TaskOne = TaskTwo!=blank
    \fi
  \fi
}
```

Please help if data = zero or blank.
Thank in advance

Comment: `\if\relax#1\relax` is not a good test

Comment: your question would be easier to answer if your code was a complete document that could be run with testcases rather than  a fragment with undefined commands in each branch

Comment: Adding to @DavidCarlisle's first comment: A better test would be `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax`.

Comment: There is also \if\empty#1\relax, but for best results use something like `\def\@tempa{#1}` to do comparisons.

Comment: If the arguments will **always** be numeric (or blank), `\newcommand{\selectTask}[2]{\ifnum9=#19\relax
    \ifnum9=#29\relax
      \selectTaskA
    \else
      \selectTaskB
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum9=#29\relax
      \selectTaskC
    \else
      \selectTaskD
    \fi
  \fi
}`

Comment: "zero or blank" - what is meant by that?  In TeX jargon an argument is "blank" when it either contains no tokens at all or contains only space tokens (character token, catcode 10(dec), charcode 32(dec)). What do you mean by "zero"? Do you mean arbitrary code whose evaluation after preceding it with `\number` yields only the character token "0" (catcode 12(dec), character code 48(dec)) and no other tokens? If you wish a check which includes whether whatsoever evaluation/expansion of arbitrary code/algorithms  yields the token "0", you beneath other problems face the so-called halting-problem.

Comment: A test for "blankness", i.e., only space tokens or no tokens at all, could be: `\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}...\if\relax\detokenize\expandafter{\firstoftwo#1{}.}\relax\expandafter\firstoftwo\else\expandafter\secondoftwo\fi{<blank>}{<not blank>}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\if\relax#1\relax`  would be true if the expansion of `#1` results in something that starts with any non-character. `\if\relax\hbox{abc}\relax` for example would test as true (and typeset `abc`).

this uses `\ifx` tests which do not expand the tested tokens.

```
\def\tmpempty{}
\def\tmpzero{0}

\newcommand{\selectTask}[2]{%
  \def\tmp{#1}\ifx\tmp\tmpempty\let\tmp\tmpzero\fi
  \def\tmpb{#2}\ifx\tmpb\tmpempty\let\tmpb\tmpzero\fi
  \ifx\tmp\tmpzero
    \ifx\tmpb\tmpzero
      \show\selectTaskA % 00 TaskOne = TaskTwo=blank => How if blank or zero?
    \else
      \show\selectTaskB % 01 TaskOne =blank,TaskTwo=!=blank
    \fi
  \else
    \ifx\tmpb\tmpzero
      \show\selectTaskC % 10  TaskOne !=blank, TaskTwo=blank
    \else
      \show\selectTaskD % 11 TaskOne = TaskTwo!=blank
    \fi
  \fi
}



\selectTask{}{}%A
\selectTask{0}{}%A
\selectTask{}{x}%B
\selectTask{0}{x}%B
\selectTask{x}{}%C
\selectTask{x}{0}%C
\selectTask{x}{y}%D





\stop
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's an implementation according to your idea: the first argument is tested if blank, if it is the following macro is called with `0` argument; similarly the second argument is tested. Then we do a string case choice.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\selectTask}{mm}
 {
  \latexforti_select_task:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\cs_new:Nn \latexforti_select_task:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #1 }
   {
    \__latexforti_select_task_a:nn { 0 } { #2 }
   }
   {
    \__latexforti_select_task_a:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__latexforti_select_task_a:nn
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nTF { #2 }
   {
    \__latexforti_select_task_b:nn { #1 } { 0 }
   }
   {
    \__latexforti_select_task_b:nn { #1 } { #2 }
   }
 }
\cs_new:Nn \__latexforti_select_task_b:nn
 {
  \str_case:nn { #1#2 }
   {
    {00}{\selectTaskA}
    {01}{\selectTaskB}
    {10}{\selectTaskC}
    {11}{\selectTaskD}
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand{\selectTaskA}{I'm task A}
\newcommand{\selectTaskB}{I'm task B}
\newcommand{\selectTaskC}{I'm task C}
\newcommand{\selectTaskD}{I'm task D}

\begin{document}

\selectTask{0}{0} --- \selectTask{}{0} -- \selectTask{0}{}

\selectTask{0}{1} --- \selectTask{}{1}

\selectTask{1}{0} --- \selectTask{1}{}

\selectTask{1}{1}

\end{document}
```

[image]

An implementation with more classical methods (but arguments cannot be `{ }` as in the previous one).

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter

\newcommand{\selectTask}[2]{%
  \expandafter\latexforti@select\expandafter
    {\number0#1\expandafter}\expandafter{\number0#2}%
}
\newcommand{\latexforti@select}[2]{%
  \ifcase\numexpr#1*2+#2\relax % the arguments are binary digits!
    \selectTaskA
  \or
    \selectTaskB
  \or
    \selectTaskC
  \or
    \selectTaskD
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\selectTaskA}{I'm task A}
\newcommand{\selectTaskB}{I'm task B}
\newcommand{\selectTaskC}{I'm task C}
\newcommand{\selectTaskD}{I'm task D}

\begin{document}

\selectTask{0}{0} --- \selectTask{}{0} -- \selectTask{0}{}

\selectTask{0}{1} --- \selectTask{}{1}

\selectTask{1}{0} --- \selectTask{1}{}

\selectTask{1}{1}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the arguments are **only** allowed to be blank or numeric, you can use an `\ifnum` comparison.

```
\documentclass[]{scrartcl}
\def\selectTaskA{00}
\def\selectTaskB{01}
\def\selectTaskC{10}
\def\selectTaskD{11}

\newcommand{\selectTask}[2]{%
  \ifnum9=#19\relax
    \ifnum9=#29\relax
      \selectTaskA
    \else
      \selectTaskB
    \fi
  \else
    \ifnum9=#29\relax
      \selectTaskC
    \else
      \selectTaskD
    \fi
  \fi
}
\begin{document}
\selectTask{}{}\\
\selectTask{0}{}\\
\selectTask{}{0}\\
\selectTask{0}{0}\\
\selectTask{}{1}\\
\selectTask{1}{}\\
\selectTask{1}{1}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a variant which is expansion-based, i.e., does without whatsoever temporary assignments.
Besides this it does without any `\if..`-primitives (which avoids problems in case the arguments themselves contain unbalanced `\if..`/`\else`/`\fi`).

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\makeatletter
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%......................................................................
%% \UD@CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                     {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                       which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherNull[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\@secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \@secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}%
  \@secondoftwo}{\expandafter\expandafter\@firstoftwo{ }{}\@firstoftwo}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only space tokens):
%%......................................................................
%% -- Take advantage of the fact that TeX discards space tokens when
%%    "fetching" _un_delimited arguments: --
%% \UD@CheckWhetherBlank{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that
%%                        argument which is to be checked is blank>}%
%%                      {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                        which is to be checked is not blank}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlank[1]{%
  \romannumeral\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\@secondoftwo
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\@firstoftwo#1{}.}%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% Check whether argument is blank (empty or only space tokens) or
%% consists only of a _single_ token "0" (charcode 48(dec), catcode 12(dec))
%%......................................................................
\newcommand\UD@GobbleToExclam{}\long\def\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!{}%
\newcommand\UD@forkzero{}\long\def\UD@forkzero#1!!0!#2#3!!!!{#2}%
\newcommand\UD@zerofork[3]{%
  \expandafter\UD@CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\UD@GobbleToExclam#1!}{%
    \UD@forkzero!#1!0!{#3}%<-case #1 is empty/has no tokens
                !!#1!{#2}%<-case #1 = "0"
                !!0!{#3}%<-case #1 something else without exclamation mark
                !!!!%
  }{#3}%<-case #1 = something else with exclamation-mark.
}%
\newcommand\UD@CheckWhetherBlankOrZero[1]{%
  \romannumeral0\UD@CheckWhetherBlank{#1}{%
    \@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@firstoftwo
  }{%
     \UD@zerofork{#1}%
     {\@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@firstoftwo}%
     {\@firstoftwo{\expandafter}{} \@secondoftwo}%
  }%
}%
%%----------------------------------------------------------------------
%% \selectTask
%%......................................................................
\newcommand{\selectTask}[2]{%
  \UD@CheckWhetherBlankOrZero{#1}{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherBlankOrZero{#2}{% <blank or zero> = either spaces or a single "0" or no tokens at all
      \selectTaskA % #1 = #2 = <blank or zero>
    }{%
      \selectTaskB % #1 = <blank or zero>; #2 =/= <blank or zero>
    }%
  }{%
    \UD@CheckWhetherBlankOrZero{#2}{%
      \selectTaskC % #1 =/= <blank or zero>; #2 = <blank or zero>
    }{%
      \selectTaskD % #1 =/= <blank or zero>; #2 =/= <blank or zero>
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand{\selectTaskA}{%
  Task A---%
  \string##1 \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle } 
  and
  \string##2 \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle }%
  .%
}
\newcommand{\selectTaskB}{%
  Task B---%
  \string##1 \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle } 
  and
  \string##2 not \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle }%
  .%
}
\newcommand{\selectTaskC}{%
  Task C---%
  \string##1 not \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle } 
  and
  \string##2 \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle }%
  .%
}
\newcommand{\selectTaskD}{%
  Task D--- %
  \string##1 not \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle } 
  and
  \string##2 not \textit{\textlangle blank or zero\textrangle }%
  .%
}
\makeatother

\parindent=0pt
\parskip=\baselineskip
\addtolength\oddsidemargin{-1.5cm}
\addtolength\evensidemargin{-1.5cm}
\addtolength\textwidth{3cm}

\begin{document}

\verb*|\selectTask{0}{0}|: \selectTask{0}{0}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{  }{0}|: \selectTask{  }{0}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{0}{  }|: \selectTask{0}{  }\\
\verb*|\selectTask{  }{  }|: \selectTask{  }{  }\\
\verb*|\selectTask{}{0}|: \selectTask{}{0}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{0}{}|: \selectTask{0}{}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{}{}|: \selectTask{}{}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{}{  }|: \selectTask{}{  }\\
\verb*|\selectTask{  }{}|: \selectTask{  }{}

\verb*|\selectTask{0}{1}|: \selectTask{0}{1}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{  }{1}|: \selectTask{  }{1}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{}{1}|: \selectTask{}{1}

\verb*|\selectTask{1}{0}|: \selectTask{1}{0}\\
\verb*|\selectTask{1}{  }|: \selectTask{1}{  }\\
\verb*|\selectTask{1}{}|: \selectTask{1}{}

\verb*|\selectTask{1}{1}|: \selectTask{1}{1}

\textbf{BUT:}

\verb*|\selectTask{00}{00}|: \selectTask{00}{00}

\verb*|\selectTask{ 0 }{ 0 }|: \selectTask{ 0 }{ 0 }

\let\implicitzero=0%
\def\expandtospace{ }%
\verb*|\let\implicitzero=0|\\
\verb*|\def\myspace{ }|\\
\verb*|\selectTask{\implicitzero}{\implicitzero}|:\\ \selectTask{\implicitzero}{\implicitzero}

\verb*|\selectTask{\expandtospace}{\expandtospace}|:\\ \selectTask{\expandtospace}{\expandtospace}

\end{document}
```

[image]